Why is $\iiint_B(12x^2+2z)dxdydz=\iiint_B4(x^2+y^2+z^2)dxdydz$?
According to my teacher
$$\iiint_B (12x^2+2z) \, dx \, dy \, dz = \iiint_B 4(x^2+y^2+z^2) \, dx\, dy\, dz$$
where $B=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1\}$. I have absolutely no clue why the triple integrals should be equal.

Have you tried to calculate these integrals?

No I haven't but according to my teacher it should be equal to $16\pi/5$.

it is easy to calculate since $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ right, but how are they equal?

what is the truth, that they are not equal? I just assume they are equal and am wondering why it is.

It has to do with symmetry considerations. The integral of $x^2$ is the same as the integral of $y^2$ which is the same as the integral of $z^2$, and by oddness the integral of $2z$ is just zero.

@perpersson No, $\le 1$, not $=1$.

@Zarrax You should write that as an answer.

How are they equal?
Odd terms:
What is $\iiint_B z \ dx\ dy\ dz$?
Without evaluating it, $z$ is odd and is being evaluated over a region that is symmetric in the $\pm z$ directions.  In fact any odd polynomial will evaluate to $0$ over this region.
We can drop the odd term from the integral on the left.
Next
$\iiint x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ dx\ dy\ dz = \iiint x^2 \ dx\ dy\ dz + \iiint y^2 \ dx\ dy\ dz + \iiint z^2 \ dx\ dy\ dz$
by linearity.   And,
$\iiint_B x^2 \ dx\ dy\ dz = \iiint_B y^2 \ dx\ dy\ dz = \iiint_B z^2 \ dx\ dy\ dz$
again by the symmetry of the region.
