What is the surface integral?
Let $u=((x+y)z,y+xz,z^2+xz)$ be a vector field and $\Sigma$ be the surface $\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{36}=1$. Calculate $\iint_{\Sigma}(u\cdot N)dS$.
So $\text{div }u=1+3z+x$ and by using gauss theorem $\iiint_K (1+x+3z)dV=\iiint_K1dV$, by symmetry. The volume of $K$ is $\frac{4}{3}\pi*3*2*6=48\pi$ but the answer should be $8\pi$ or $-8\pi$. What is wrong here?

What "symmetry" are you referring to here?

Symmetry in the $+-z$, $+-x$ direction.  I asked this question 2 days ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4900361/why-is-iiint-b12x22zdxdydz-iiint-b4x2y2z2dxdydz

I don't see anything wrong with your work as written. The supposed "answer" is wrong.

The answer is given by my teacher. He calculated the volume and derived the answer from it without explaining.
